# Not valid template file in magento

Tags: magento-1, template

I have added the following to local.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <contacts_index_index translate="label">
        <label>Contact Us Form</label>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="contacts"><title>Contact Us</title></action>
        </reference>
    </contacts_index_index>
    <customer_account_forgotpassword translate="label">
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Forgot Your Password</title></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_forgotpassword>
    <checkout_onepage_success>
        <reference name="head">
            <block type="core/template" name="cj_udo" template="app/design/frontend/base/default/template/cj/udo.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_success>
</layout>
```

location:

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/local.xml
```

then I added `udo.phtml` here:
[image: http://screencast.com/t/Hj9VRuFYC7]

However I get this error on my system.log

> 2014-08-10T11:51:36+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template
>   file:frontend/base/default/template/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/cj/udo.phtmlt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**don't need to put full template path**

```
<block type="core/template" name="cj_udo" template="app/design/frontend/base/default/template/cj/udo.phtml" />
```

**Should be**

```
 <block type="core/template" name="cj_udo" template="cj/udo.phtml" />
```

Comment: great, that fixed, the problem, thank you, maybe you know how to fix this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25224251/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory-in-varien-autoload-php-on-line

Comment: its done, its just that I cant accept answers so fast, the website doesnt allow it

Comment: k,it will see..